# JOOQ record caching exception

Tags: redis, jooq

I am trying to cache JOOQ record result using redis. But the same is throwing the following error:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jooq.impl.Utils$Cache$Key
```

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same issue as https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5290, which is a bug in jOOQ 3.8.1

I can see two workarounds around this issue:

- You explicitly "detach" your records prior to serialisation in redis by calling `Record.detach()`
- You turn off automatic attaching of records to the creating `Configuration` using the `Settings.attachRecords` property

In both cases, should you wish to retrieve a record from redis and store it again, you will need to explicitly call `Record.attach(Configuration)`